# iOS - Mocking UserDefault before loading the view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, unit-testing, testing

I am currently working on test for my application and I have faced a problem when mocking user defaults. Let me first show you my setup :

this is how I mock user Defaults :

```
class MockUserDefaults: UserDefaults {

    typealias FakeData = Dictionary<String, Any?>
    var data: FakeData

    convenience init() {
        self.init(suiteName: "mocking")!
    }

    override init?(suiteName suitename: String?) {
        data = FakeDefaults()
        UserDefaults().removePersistentDomain(forName: suitename!)
        super.init(suiteName: suitename)
    }

    override func object(forKey defaultName: String) -> Any? {
        if let data = data[defaultName] {
            return data
        }
        return nil
    }

    override func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String) {
        if defaultName == "favs"{
            data[defaultName] = value
        }

    }

}
```

I have a variable in my view controller called : userDefaults, and I set it like this :

```
var userDefaults : UserDefaults {
        if (NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil) {
            return MockUserDefaults()
        }
        return UserDefaults.standard
    }
```

this variable is actually an extension to a protocol which a made uiviewcontroller conform to it to make sure all my view controllers have this variable.

I also have a variable in myViewcontroller called favoriteMovie which I set like this :

```
private var favoriteMovie: Favorite? {
    if let favoriteString = userDefaults.value(forKey: "favs") as? String {
        return favorites.first(where: {$0.name == favoriteString})
    }
    return nil   
}
```

now here's where the problem is, when I go and try to test this view controller , I need to set userDefault with an object for example :

```
    myviewController.userDefaults.set("avengers", forKey: "favs")
```

before the test runs, but the problem is that favoriteMovie variable always return nil and I need it to return an object before the test runs . Any help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :

this is the protocol :

```
protocol Mockable: class {
    var userDefaults: UserDefaults { get }
}
```

this is the extension :

```
extension UIViewController: Mockable {}
extension Mockable {
        var userDefaults : UserDefaults {
            if (NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil) {
                return MockUserDefaults()
            }
            return UserDefaults.standard
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are two ways to fix it.**

**1)** By doing some DI. In you `viewController` declare `userDefaults` as non-computed property as below

```
var userDefaults : UserDefaults?
```

In your test case, create `MockUserDefaults` object, set values and assign it to `viewController` when you are initiating it as below,

```
let mockUD = MockUserDefaults()
mockUD.set("avengers", forKey: "favs")

myviewController.userDefaults = mockUD
```

Now you will get the `avengers` object.

**2)** As the question is updated, here is the fix to hold the `mockDefaults` object,

```
struct AssociatedMock {
    static var key: UInt8 = 0
}

extension Mockable {

    private (set) var _mockDefaults: MockUserDefaults? {
        get {
            guard let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedMock.key) as? MockUserDefaults else {
                return nil
            }
            return value
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedMock.key, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }

    var userDefaults : UserDefaults {
        if (NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil) {
            if self._mockDefaults == nil {
                self._mockDefaults = MockUserDefaults()
            }
            return self._mockDefaults!
        }
        return UserDefaults.standard
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I don't know if you saw my edited question or not, but as I said there, userDefaults is an extension to protocol which I made all uiviewcontrollers conform to it so I can access that variable in all of them, but when i go for your second suggestion and add _mockDefaults to the extension I get this error "Extensions must not contain stored properties", what do you think?

Comment: Ok, then update your question with protocol and extension to get a better idea.

Comment: @Kilom94l try now as i updated the answer according to the code you shared.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. If you have time can you please explain it to me ?

Comment: Yes, actually in the userDefaults, you were always returning a new object of `MockUserDefaults` means it will have empty data. The MockUserDefaults object was different at saving and retrieving the `favs` value. In my solution, i am creating MockUserDefaults only once when it is nil otherwise i return the same object. That's why your `favs` value is retrieving properly as it is the same object that you used at the time of saving.

Comment: got it. Thank you for your time :)